# When i fswatch a particular folder in mac , i get renamed is file for both addition and deletion of files in folder

Tags: macos, fswatch

I am monitoring a particular folder in mac os by giving in commandline

```
 fswatch -x /Users/syammala/folder
```

> /Users/syammala/folder/posixGroup.xml Renamed IsFile

Whenever i add or delete a file i always get renamed is file. I want to differentiate the action, when i add and delete files

Comment: What is `fswatch`? It's not a command that's built into OS X. How about you ask whoever provides it? In any case, this isn't a question about programming or developer tools, so isn't appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: fswatch is cross platform monitor which uses FSevents in MAC OSX. As far as i know when we give this in commandline, it displays events occured on particular Folder location we mentioned. But for addition and deletion i get same message displayed. I want to know can we do any programatical changes to get what action is performed actually on the folder

Comment: You're looking to modify `fswatch`'s code? Then you need to show the code that it currently uses and ask some specific question about it.

Comment: Where can i get fswatch code to modify. If some one can suggest that will it come under programming question? please help me to solve this issue

Comment: I know this is four years too late, @Dutt, but fswatch is available on GitHub, under a GPL license.  Download and modify your heart out. https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

As you have now clarified that you are moving and deleting files *using the Finder*, it makes life more complicated because when you use the Finder it interacts with the Trashcan unlike when you use the Terminal and Unix commands. So, when you delete a file in Finder, it **renames** the file into the Trashcan which is stored in `$HOME/.Trash`.

So, you effectively need to monitor the Trashcan as well as wherever you were planning on monitoring like this:

```
fswatch -x FolderA $HOME/.Trash
```

then you will see everything that is happening.

Alternatively, disable the Trashcan - which I appreciate may not be acceptable however you do not provide much detail of your environment, so I don't know.

To disable the Trashcan, remove the `$HOME/.Trash` directory and all its contents, and then create a file called `$HOME/.Trash` so that OSX cannot recreate its beloved Trashcan there. **Do not do this if you don't understand it!**

```
cd
rm -rf .Trash
touch .Trash
```

To later re-enable the Trashcan, do this:

```
cd
rm .Trash
```

**Original Answer**

You can do it like this with numeric flags.

If you do this:

```
touch FreddyFrog
rm FreddyFrog

touch BozoBrains
mv BozoBrains SillyBilly
rm SillyBilly
```

you can monitor like this

```
fswatch -xn `pwd`
/Users/mark/tmp/FreddyFrog 514     # touch FreddyFrog
/Users/mark/tmp/FreddyFrog 520     # rm FreddyFrog

/Users/mark/tmp/BozoBrains 514     # touch BozoBrains
/Users/mark/tmp/BozoBrains 528     # mv BozoBrains SillyBilly
/Users/mark/tmp/SillyBilly 528     # mv BozoBrains SillyBilly
/Users/mark/tmp/SillyBilly 520     # rm SillyBilly
```

Comment: When i move files from command line and delete files from command line i am getting the same 528. And also when i drag and drop files in to the folder and outside the folder i am getting this same 528. I want to distinguish this each action in the folder

Comment: So if you repeat the exact commands I showed, you always get 528, never 514, never 520? Is that correct? What version of OSX are you using?

Comment: We do get 514 when we create as touch file and 520 for rm file. What i am saying is for drag and drop and deletion we are always getting 528.

Comment: Ok, my guess is that when you do GUI drag&drop operations, it actually **moves** the files to the Trashcan, so deletions and renames appear the same. Try disabling the Trashcan for the volume temporarily to check.